# how to convert matplotlib Figure to binary type

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, dropbox

is there any way that I can convert matplotlib Figure  to binary type  so that I can upload the image to dropbox

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("token")
df = pd.DataFrame({
'City': ['Saharanpur', 'Meerut', 'Saharanpur', 'Saharanpur', 'Meerut'],
'intents': ['greeting', 'greting', 'warn', 'welcome', 'welcome'],
'data': [21000, 22000, 21000, 22000, 22000]})
figure=df['intents'].value_counts().plot.pie(label='', autopct='%1.0f%%',figsize =(15, 10)).figure
dbx.files_upload(figure, '/project/file1.png', mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
```

the  error which I am  getting is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-91484029198d> in <module>
----> 1 dbx.files_upload(figure, '/project/file1.png', mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)

C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py in files_upload(self, f, path, mode, autorename, client_modified, mute, property_groups, strict_conflict)
   2859                                property_groups,
   2860                                strict_conflict)
-> 2861         r = self.request(
   2862             files.upload,
   2863             'files',

C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py in request(self, route, namespace, request_arg, request_binary, timeout)
    319             timeout = request_arg.timeout + 90
    320 
--> 321         res = self.request_json_string_with_retry(host,
    322                                                   route_name,
    323                                                   route_style,

C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py in request_json_string_with_retry(self, host, route_name, route_style, request_json_arg, auth_type, request_binary, timeout)
    475             self._logger.info('Request to %s', route_name)
    476             try:
--> 477                 return self.request_json_string(host,
    478                                                 route_name,
    479                                                 route_style,

C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py in request_json_string(self, host, func_name, route_style, request_json_arg, auth_type, request_binary, timeout)
    537             # behavior when a non-rewindable stream is read from, but the
    538             # request fails and needs to be re-tried at a later time.
--> 539             raise TypeError('expected request_binary as binary type, got %s' %
    540                             type(request_binary))
    541 

TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'method'>
```

I know that we can save the figure to local like

```
df['intents'].value_counts().plot.pie(label='', autopct='%1.0f%%',figsize =(15, 10)).figure.savefig('D:/chat2/file.png')
```

then from local, I can upload to dropbox

```
dbx.files_upload('D:/chat2/file.png', '/project/file1.png', mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
```

Is there any way that I can directly upload to dropbox?

Thanks

Comment: You could save to a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) and then upload the tempfile to dropbox. That way, after the program execution is done, nothing should be saved to your local machine.

Comment: Have you tried io.Bytes() already https://mellowd.dev/python/using-io-bytesio/

Comment: @ai2ys yes tried that one will get 
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class '_io.BytesIO'>